# How do I add one more year to the given input?

Tags: ruby

I want to get an output so that it adds one more year to an age input.

This is my code:

```
print "Age: "
age = gets.chomp.to_i

def age_next_year(int)
  age.each do |int|
  int += 1
end

puts "Next year I’ll be " + age_next_year(age)
```

I can't seem to get the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to call `each` since it’s designed to iterate *arrays* and you have an integer. Also, you don’t need to reassign the value back to `int` local variable, just return it from the method:

```
def age_next_year(int)
  int + 1
end
```

Another issue is you are trying to `+` what `age_next_year` method returns (integer) to the string. The explicit conversion is required there:

```
puts "Next year I’ll be " + age_next_year(age).to_s
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I still get the following wrong message though "no implicit conversion of Integer into String". I don't understand where I'm supposed to do this conversion? Isn't my first conversion in the beginning enough? :) thanks!

Comment: Ah, indeed. Updated the answer.

Comment: Oh! Ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just asking, but why don't you do something like this:

```rb
print "Age: "
age = gets.chomp.to_i + 1
printf "Next year I'll be %d\n", age
# OR
puts "Next year I'll be " + age.to_s
```

It works fine for me, and it's smaller and quicker than what you did.